# Удалить строку tr из table

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. Я реализовал такой код удаления данных из БД через Ajax:

```
 $(".delalbumimg").on("click", function(){
    var res = confirm("Подтвердите удаление");
    if(!res) return false;

    var img = $(this).attr("alt"); //имя картинки
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel"); //флаг картинки(0-базовая, 1-галлерея)
    var album_id = $("#album_id").text(); //ID автора
    $.ajax({
      url: "./",
      type: "POST",
      data:{album_image: img, rel: rel, album_id: album_id},
      success: function(res){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        alert(this);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("Ошибка");
      }
    });
});
```

В случае успеха мне нужно удалить строку(как правило, без перезагрузки страницы), в которой находилось удаленное фото. Как реализовать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас в success уже другая область видимости и другой this. Запишите в обработчике клика целевой элемент в переменную и обращайтесь в обработчике success к ней а не к this.

```
$(".delalbumimg").on("click", function(e){
 var el=e.target;
 var res = confirm("Подтвердите удаление");
 if(!res) return false;

 var img = $(this).attr("alt"); //имя картинки
 var rel = $(this).attr("rel"); //флаг картинки(0-базовая, 1-галлерея)
 var album_id = $("#album_id").text(); //ID автора
 $.ajax({
   url: "./",
   type: "POST",
   data:{album_image: img, rel: rel, album_id: album_id},
   success: function(res){
     $(el).closest("tr").remove();
     alert(this);
   },
   error: function(){
     alert("Ошибка");
   }
 });
});
```

Еще есть вариант с bind, если вам так хочется использовать именно this, но всё что я про него скажу - лучше так не делать.

Answer (score 0):

Внутри success `$(this)` уже не тот.

Если так?

```
$(".delalbumimg").on("click", function(){
    var res = confirm("Подтвердите удаление");
    if(!res) return false;

    self = $(this);
    var img = $(this).attr("alt"); //имя картинки
    var rel = $(this).attr("rel"); //флаг картинки(0-базовая, 1-галлерея)
    var album_id = $("#album_id").text(); //ID автора
    $.ajax({
      url: "./",
      type: "POST",
      data:{album_image: img, rel: rel, album_id: album_id},
      success: function(res){
        self.closest("tr").remove();
        alert(this);
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("Ошибка");
      }
    });
});
```